# NHibernate Time conversion issue when fetching from Database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am facing a time conversion problem. In one of my tables, I store time data by using the following class:

---

```
public class HistoryData
{
    public virtual int HD_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime HD_DATE { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime HD_TIME { get; set; } /* this is my time data */
    public virtual EquipmentSensor HD_EQUIPMENT { get; set; }
    public virtual float HD_VALUE { get; set; }
    public virtual HistoryDataType HD_TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my method :

```
public List<HistoryData> getMeasures()
{
      var query = " my sql query ";
      var result = (List<HistoryData>)this.session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                        .List<HistoryData>();

      return result;

 }
```

Here is the SQL Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORY_DATA
(
    HD_ID               INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY,
    HD_DATE             DATE            NOT NULL            ,
    HD_TIME             TIME(0)         NOT NULL            ,
    HD_EQU_ID           INT             NOT NULL            ,
    HD_VALUE            DECIMAL(18,1)   NULL                ,
    HD_TYPE_ID          INT             NOT NULL            
)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
{"Input string '00:01:01' was not in the correct format."}
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'."}
could not execute query
```

Here is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping
xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
assembly="DaFyDaC"
namespace="DaFyDaC.Models.KPIs"
auto-import="true">
  <class name="DaFyDaC.Models.KPIs.HistoryData, DaFyDaC" table="HISTORY_DATA">
    <id name="HD_ID" access="property" type="int">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="HD_DATE" type="Date"/>
    <property name="HD_TIME" type="Time"/>
    <property name="HD_VALUE" type="float"/>
    <many-to-one class="DaFyDaC.Models.Configuration.EquipmentSensor" name="HD_EQUIPMENT" column="HD_EQU_ID" not-found="ignore"/>
    <many-to-one class="HistoryDataType" name="HD_TYPE" column="HDT_ID" not-found="ignore"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Could you please help me to fix it ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, your property HD_TIME should be TimeSpan rather than DateTime to work with NHibernate out of the box.  You can get it to work with DateTime via your mappings if need be.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

The HD_TIME column is converted to a System.TimeSpan, make your data type of the TD_TIME a TimeSpan:

```
public virtual TimeSpan HD_TIME { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# property definition should be of a type `TimeSpan`

```
public virtual TimeSpan HD_TIME { get; set; }
```

The xml mapping should look like this:

```
<property name="HD_TIME" type="Time" 
          type="NHibernate.Type.TimeAsTimeSpanType" />
```

Why this? because `TimeSpan` is by default represented (for NHibernate) as `DbType.Int64`. But the **`TimeAsTimeSpanType`** will allow us to use it with Time like DB type...

*see also [5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)*

**Querying**

Having this mapping in place, we can even query such column. E.g. to find all records tracked between 12:00 and 18:00 we can use query like this:

```
var lowerBound = new TimeSpan(0, 12, 0, 0);
var upperBound = new TimeSpan(0, 18, 0, 0);

var query = session.QueryOver<HistoryData>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.HD_TIME)
        .IsBetween(lowerBound)
        .And(upperBound)
    ...
    .Take(10) // paging
    .Skip(10)
    ;

var result = query.List<HistoryData>();
```

very important note here is, that the NHibernate Factory configuration cannot be *(often usual)*

```
<property
    name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
```

But must be **`Sql2008ClientDriver`**

```
<property 
    name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver</property>
```

(even for SQL Server 2012+)

Answer (score 0):

The proper type to use for time data is TimeSpan. All ADO.Net providers map time types (if they are available) to this type, not DateTime. ORMs like NHibernate and Entity Framework follow the ADO.Net conventions unless overriden by a provider, so time types are mapped to TimeSpan.

Change

```
public virtual DateTime HD_TIME { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual TimeSpan HD_TIME { get; set; }
```

Also make sure you update your mappings to reflect the new type.

Comment: the hd_date property works fine. but I am still having the same error.

Comment: Ooops, copied the wrong line. It's `HD_TIME` that must be changed